# Research Request for a Paper of A.M. Leontovich

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a digital copy of a the English version of the paper "The Number of Mappings of Graphs, Ordering of Graphs, and Muirhead's Theorem" by A.M. Leontovich. The math.ru link to the paper is http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ppi&paperid=654&option_lang=eng so if anybody happens to have a translation of the paper handy that would also be useful.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but some of the results in that paper are discussed quite usefully here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X94903883

Comment: The purpose of the question was actually to find the counterexample by Leontovich that Siderenko mentions for showing that T10 and T11 in the paper are incomparable; this is unfortunately not mentioned in the paper.

Comment: You may want to check Remark 4.13 in https://doi.org/10.37236/4096.